# GWT SimpleBeanEditorDriver - generate editor class

Tags: gwt, gxt

I've seen many questions in stackoverflow that are similar to mine, but haven't seen problem described as mine. So, here is the question:

I am building quite huge web application using GXT. I need to make couple of hundreds windows with editable fields. What I want is to make generator that would generate Editor UI according to DataModel in runtime. But I can't see how this can be done as Editor field names has to match DataModel field names (@Path annotation can be used as well). Either way knowing this it is not possible to generate fields based on DataModel field list in runtime. The Editor class has to be built at compile time. Is there a way I could generate editor fields in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

This would require at least the model to be identified but something like this would build you a basic UI for your model.

```
 public void BuildUI(TargetFieldMapping model) {
      //Generate a factory for this model to cover to BeanModel
      BeanModelFactory curFactory = BeanModelLookup.get().getFactory(model.getClass());

      //Create a bean from this model
      BeanModel bean = curFactory.createModel(model);

      //Loop through the properties
      for(String s : bean.getPropertyNames()) {
          //Get value
          Object obj = bean.get(s);

          //for each data type generate a different field type
          if(obj instanceof Integer) {
              NumberField field = new NumberField();
              field.setName(s);
              field.setFieldLabel(s);
              add(field);
          }
          //Etc etc...
      }
}
```

Hope this gets you on the right track

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using GXT 3.0. There is no more BeanModelFactory. Besides, I've found out that all the Editors have to be built in compile time as GWT SimpleBeanEditorDriver uses reflection to compile working js code. So I guess it is not possible to build Editor view in runtime. Instead one have to make generator that would generate Editor's view in compile time.